# Support of Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, fourier-restriction

Consider the unit sphere $\mathcal{S}^n$. Let $Q$ be a cube contained in the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathcal{S}^n$ defined by
$$ E = \{ (x,\sqrt{1-|x|^2}) : x \in Q \}. $$

Let $ f \in  L^2(\mathcal{S}^n) $, then one may define the Fourier transform,

$$  \widehat{f \sigma}(x) = \int_{\mathcal{S}^n} e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot \xi} f(\xi)\ d \sigma(\xi)$$

for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$

This is well defined and by Tomas-Stein, $\widehat{f \sigma} \in L^\frac{2(n+2)}{n}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}). $

Can someone help me understand the support of the Fourier transform of $\widehat{f\chi_E\sigma}$. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Fourier transforms of compactly-supported distributions are entire functions...? Paley-Wiener stuff?

Comment: I am not sure if Paley-Wiener is the way to approach this. I read in an article that the support would be contained in $E \times \mathbb{R}$ ( not sure how though). I wanted to know if this can be further refined.